# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(f\left(\frac{1}{n^{2/3}}\right)\right)^{2}$ is convergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(f\left(\frac{1}{n^{2/3}}\right)\right)^{2}$$ is convergent.

It's given that $f\in C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ and $f(0)=0$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that if $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ is removed then the statement is not true ($f(x) = x^{3/4}$ would be a counter-example). What does $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ tell you about how $f$ behaves close to $x=0$?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** An approach is to use the fact that $f\in C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ and $f(0)=0$ to write by Taylor expansion, as $x \to 0$,
$$
f(x)=f'(0)\:x+\mathcal{O}(x^2)
$$ giving, as $n \to +\infty$,
$$
f\left(\frac{1}{n^{2/3}}\right)=f'(0)\:\frac{1}{n^{2/3}}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^{4/3}}\right)
$$ and
$$
\left(f\left(\frac{1}{n^{2/3}}\right)\right)^2=(f'(0))^2\:\frac{1}{n^{4/3}}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right) \quad (2/3+4/3=2)
$$ leading to the **convergence** of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(f\left(\frac{1}{n^{2/3}}\right)\right)^2 $.